Overwriting all the elements of the list with the last element in for-loop in R
I have this this code for making a ppt from R:
library(officer)

pres <- read_pptx("E:/ZEM Solutions/Iz R-a u Power Point/ZEM_Template za migrenu.pptx")

title_s1 <- "Trial"
subtitle_s1 <- "Some subtitle"
paragraph_1_s1 <- "Paragraph 1"
paragraph_2_s1 <- "Paragraph 2"
headline_capture_s1 <- "Capture"

ph <- function(x, ph_value, ph_name) {
  ph_with(x, value = ph_value, location = ph_location_label(ph_label = ph_name))
}

placeholder <- function(x,
                        title = NULL,
                        subtitle = NULL,
                        paragraphs = NULL,
                        headline_capture = NULL) {
  
  ph_title <- \(x)  if (!is.null(title)) ph(x, title, "Trial") else x
  
  ph_subtitle <- \(x)  if (!is.null(subtitle)) ph(x, subtitle, "Some subtitle") else x
  
  ph_paragraph <- list()
  if(!is.null(paragraphs)){
    num_par <- length(paragraphs)
    for (i in 1:num_par){
      ph_paragraph[[i]] <- \(x) if (!is.null(paragraphs)) ph(x, paragraphs[[i]], paste("Paragraph ", i,  sep = "")) else x
    }
  }
  
  ph_headline_capture <- \(x)  if (!is.null(headline_capture)) ph(x, headline_capture, "Capture") else x
  
  
  
  funcS <- "  x |> \n ph_title() |> \n ph_subtitle() |> \n"
  if(length(ph_paragraph) > 0)
    for (i in 1:length(ph_paragraph)) {                      
      funcS <- CONCAT(funcS, "ph_paragraph[[",i,"]]() |> \n ")
    }
  funcS <- CONCAT(funcS, "ph_headline_capture()")
  eval(parse(text = funcS))   
  
}
  

my_pres <- pres |> 
  add_slide(layout = "PROBA", master = "Office Theme") |>
  placeholder(
    title = title_s1, 
    subtitle = subtitle_s1,
    paragraphs = c(paragraph_1_s1,
                   paragraph_2_s1),
    headline_capture <- headline_capture_s1
  )

print(my_pres, "Doc trial 2.pptx")


and it makes me a document with a slide in it, but with only the second paragraph on the slide, ignoring the first one.
Can somebody help me, please, solving this problem? It, obviously, overwrites the first parameter with the second one, but I don't know what to change in order to get them both.
